# Unable to select the repository where to download the packages

Tags: miktex2.9, miktex-update, repositories, console

For several months I want to know after an old update the reason because the `MikTeX` console doesn't give me the possibility to choose the server where to download the packages both in user and administrator mode: to see **Install from: a random package repository on the internet**. Clicking on **Connection Settings**, as I have always done, I find the window below - use a proxy server.

> Why does this happen?

**Addendum the sequence of the screenshots:**

One:

[image]

Two:

[image]

Three:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection settings button is the wrong one. In my miktex there is a "next" button:

[image]

If it is missing for you this looks like a bug. Check for updates (in user mode *and* admin mode) and if this doesn't help open an issue in the miktex issue tracker.

As a work around you can try to click on the small arrow here:

[image]

In the drop dow menu there should be at least one fix repository:

[image]

Comment: Hiii, excuse me if I disturb you. But, peraphs, six months ago I have not the NEXT BUTTON below. :-( See the sequences.

Comment: As I wrote: Check for updates, and if this persists make a bug report. Only the miktex maintainer can help you: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex

Comment: Very kind Ulrike I have always check for updates. Look the first image Last checked 13 set 2020. It is always the same. I hope to not lost my MikTeX that works correctly.

Comment: My issue has been deleted: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/619. I not able to write the problem. :-( Can you help me, if is it possible? For me not is very very important. MikTeX works perfectly.